# Why does $_POST have a larger size limit than $_GET?

Tags: php, post

I know that $_POST has a larger size limit than $_GET, but why? What is $_GET limited by?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_GET` is transferred within the url and is therefore limited by its maximum size. Where there is no theoretical maximum url size defined with the [HTTP standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), it is limited by many browsers and servers. Refer to this [FAQ](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) which advices your application to use urls that are smaller than 2000 chars

`$_POST` is transfererred within the request body which is also theoretical unlimited, but as with `$_GET` there are limits by browsers and servers. But they are usually much higher.

For you info: To adjust the maximum post size in php use the ini value

```
post_max_size=...
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the way HTTP was defined. GET is intended to be used mainly for getting data, whilst POST is for sending data.

Some details on limitations and differences: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 3):

GET parameters are all passed as a part of the URL. URL length is limited, depending on the browser and web server; the biggest limitation is IE, which [limits URLs to 2083 bytes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).

Answer (score 1):

The GET method adds the data to the URL; and the length of a URL is limited (maximum URL length is 2048 characters).